# How to get a server ready for hosting a website?

Tags: linux, email-server, lamp

Currently, my companies' website is hosted on a web hosting company which they provide everything (`WHM`, `cPanel`, `E-mail server`, `LAMP`, `security` and etc...)

We have to move the website to a private company. And we (for the first time) have to set up the server from scratch. Now, we already know what server specs must be and they are going to provide it.

It is obvious that we need to install LAMP, but what else is required to get the server ready for hosting a website? (i.e. for security or for E-mail server)

We prefer to run it by using open source software, so using a cPanel is not really important. We are open for suggestions

Comment: I would suggest to use ispconfig, they provide the tutorials on how to setup the server in a proper way and install their control panel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a server ready?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1004404/how-to-get-a-server-ready)

Comment: How do you define "ready"? Building a complete enterprise ready stack from free open source software can be very tedious and is sure way to complex for a simple Q&A. What exactly are you expecting as answer? Maybe the names of possible open source software to use?

Comment: @DarkVex thanks, i sure will check it out. Good to know some sources

Comment: @chrisl let me give you an example: I can install LAMP, but LAMP doesn't cover everything like E-mail server, right? So do I have to start with E-mail server and then go for LAMP? Is there anything else besides these two that I have to do in order to be able to host my own website?

Comment: Often Email and webserver don't have much do to with each other. It depends on the software, that you want to use, and the exact requirements. My personal email server (combination of postfix, dovecot, fetchmail, mailassasin, ...) for example does not have a web interface, thus it has nothing to do with the webserver and can be installed in parallel. I needed to dig rather far into mail servers for setting this up, and I must say, that I still feel more like scratching the surface. It can be very complex.

Comment: I think you should divide the whole project into smaller parts, which then can be implemented securely independent of another (right after you have wrote down all your requirements and researched the fitting software solutions for them).

Comment: @chrisl this is what I was looking for,  some real experience.